# Which parameter data types in a Python toolbox for selecting a path

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, parameters, python-toolbox

I need to select a SDE PATH based on user selection on Python toolbox at ArcGIS Pro 2.7.1 and use this path

[image]

at the code for setting like

```
fc = 'Zone'
SDEDir = inputPath
arcpy.management.CalculateField(r"F:\\Pro\\AreaProject\\SEV_SDE.sde\\" + fc, 
                                "PROJECTT", 
                                ....
                                "PYTHON")
```

so the final code looks like

```
fc = 'Zone'
SDEDir = inputPath
arcpy.management.CalculateField(SDEDir  + fc, 
                                "PROJECTT", 
                                ....
                                "PYTHON")
```

What data type I can use to grab the selected SDE Path? I already used `File` and `Database Connection` but they are not giving me the PATH

Comment: A ".sde" file is a connection file, which is a type of workspace.

Comment: thanks Vince and can you please let me know how to get the value of workspace in the code? I only have one parameter and it's name is `SDE`

Comment: You can't look up the name of a workspace parameter in the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)? Note that "SDE" no longer exists, so naming things "SDE" is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go back and re-evaluate your workflow. Generally when executing geoprocessing tools (custom or otherwise), a user navigates directly to the feature class when the tool requires it (your workflow shows CalcField: this requires a FC). You're asking for the user to navigate to a `.sde` file, and then inside the tool you've hardcoded it to a particular feature class name. Your tool attempts to guide/help the user, but it's a confusing effort because the user could simply point at the wrong `.sde` connection and your tool will fail because it cannot find the right feature class inside.

I'd suggest switching your parameter to `DEFeatureClass` (a feature class). This means the box will allow someone to navigate to a `.sde`, double click "into" the workspace, and choose the feature class they want.

If you really want to keep with selecting just the workspace, but do not have them select the feature class pattern, you can use `DEWorkspace`. **However**, once inside the tool, this does NOT return the path to your workspace (`.sde`), it returns the actual workspace; that is a parameter type some tools make use of. Since you only want the path, you'll need to do a little work.

**getParameterInfo**

```
param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Input workspace",
    name="in_workspace",
    datatype="DEWorkspace",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")
```

**execute**

```
    desc = parameters[0].valueAsText

    arcpy.management.CalculateField(desc + ".sde\\" + fc, 
                                "PROJECTT", 
                                ....
                                "PYTHON")
```

[Parameter type references](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm)

Comment: @user2856 thanks. I knew there had to be a faster way: I couldn't find it in my quick google search so opted for trusty old `Describe`. I updated my answer